# Is there any interface to manually set backbone's model unchanged?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model

I'm developing a SPA app based on `backbone`, and recently I encountered an issue.

Let's say there are 2 pages: the first page is the `type` page which the user can choose one type of different forms to fill in, and the second page is the `form` page which the user can fill their info in this page. I used `backbone's router` to make it a SPA.

In the `form` page, if the user wants to changed the form type, he/she can click the `previous` button in the `form` page to get back to the `type` page. But before the page really gets jumped, I wanna make sure that if the `info` model has been changed, I will alert a panel to remind the user to save their info before jumping to the `type` page. So I called the `info` model's `hasChanged` method everytime the users clicks the `previous` button.

And now, the page jumped to the `type` page, the users selected another type, and then go to the `info` page again.

And now is the moment, before the user fills any info, if the user clicks the `previous` button again, my code will check the model's `hasChanged` method. And since the first step which the user filled the first type's form info, the model's `hasChanged` method will always return true to me. So how to reset the model's changed flag(if there is any) everytime when the second page(`info` page) has been loaded?

Just set the model's `changed` attributes to an empty object? I don't think this is the correct way. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

why is single model used for two different forms? if they contain same data why two different forms? I would say you have to create two different type of models for your forms.If you still think the share same things then create two instances of model and associate them with the form.

i don't think there is clean way of doing using same instance of model.

Comment: The first page is to set the `type` property of the model, and the second page is to set the other properties of the model. Due to the interface requirement, the whole process has been divided into 2 pages. So here I don't think there is a need to use 2 different instances of the model.